# How to use gantt.destructor()?

Tags: vue.js, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I use DHTMLX GANTT with Vue.

When a gantt is created, and i change to another page and i return, there are not all functions available.

In the dhtmlx forum they give a link to : https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__multiple_gantts.html

But the method `const ganttChart = Gantt.getGanttInstance();`is not defined if i try to do the same in my application.

Is there a way to completely destroy a component in vue? I tried with `v-if`, with `:key`, with `$forceUpdate()` but no success. There remains still some gantt components in the DOM. When i refresh the page, it works.

Is there another way to destroy the component that he render from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gantt.destructor function gave me some problems too in Vue.

I solved it changing the gantt reference and detaching the events attached during the initialize in the like beforeDestroy Vue lifecycle, like this:

```
<div class="gantt" :id="ganttId"></div>

mounted () {
   this.ganttId = 'gantt-' + this.createUUID()
   this.initializeGannt()
}

beforeDestroy() {
    gantt.detachEvent("onTaskClick");
    gantt.detachEvent("onAfterTaskUpdate");
}

methods {
    initializeGannt () {
        ...
        gantt.attachEvent("onTaskClick", (id, e) => {
          ...
        }, {id: "onTaskClick"});

        gantt.attachEvent("onAfterTaskUpdate", (id, e) => {
          ...
        }, {id: "onAfterTaskUpdate"});
        ...
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `Gantt` object exists only in the Trial, Enterprise, and Ultimate versions.

To destroy the Gantt instance, you can call the `gantt.destructor` method:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_destructor.html

It will work in all Gantt versions. That method should destroy the Gantt container, though, its resize watcher remains:

http://prnt.sc/vkwmdw

After Gantt is destroyed, you are not able to use it again until you reload the page or create a new Gantt instance.

Comment: But how can i create a new instance?

Comment: To create a new Gantt instance, you need to use the `Gantt.getGanttInstance` method.
If that method is not available, probably, you are using the Standard or Commercial Pro version. Or you use it in a place where Gantt is not loaded.